# Google Sheet Dump with ALL Files/URLS/Owners/LastEdit dates in My Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

It's been a wee while.

This is my first venture into the DriveApp.

My goal - To obtain a list of all Documents/Spreadsheets in my drive + Subfolders. With a list of the Spreadsheet owners, urls and last edit date (if possible).

I have tried a few variations, and have been able to obtain a list of files within a folder but not my drive? Probably an issue on my end.

The Script I have currently is :

```
function getfiles() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Raw");

  var files = DriveApp.getFiles();

  var rows = [[ "Owner", "Name", "Link","Last updated"]];

  while ( files.hasNext()){

    var file = files.next();

    try { 

      var owner = file.getOwner();
      var name = file.getName();
      var url = '<a href="' + file.getUrl() + '">' + file.getName() + '</a>';
      var lup = file.getLastUpdated();

      var owners = [];
      var names = [];
      var urls = [];
      var lups = [];

      for (var v=0; owner.length;v++){
        owners.push(owner[v].getName());
      }
      for (var i=0; name.length; v++){
        names.push(name[i]);
      }
      for (var k=0; url.length; k++){
        urls.push(url[k]);
      }
      for (var o=0; lup.length; o++){
        lups.push(lup[o]);
      }


  sheet.getRange(1,1,owners.length,owners[0].length).setValues(owners);
      sheet.getRange(1,2,names.length,names[0].length).setValues(names);
      sheet.getRange(1,3,urls.length,urls[0].length).setValues(urls);
      sheet.getRange(1,4,lups.length,lups[0].length).setValues(lups);




    } catch (err) { 

      Logger.log(err);
    }
  }
}
```

This script exceeds max execution time.

Honestly, I'm still a novice. Looking for a few pointers. If you can correct my mistake and tell me how/where I've went wrong it would be much appreciated. Alternatively, point me in the right direction.

Any advice is welcomed!

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So its turns out some sleep and a fresh head managed to resolve this for me. Works wonders.

This was my end result, after about 4 revisions.

```
  function getAllFiles() {

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Test");
var arr = [["Filename", "Link", "Owner", "Last Edit Date"]];
var f = DriveApp.getFiles()
while (f.hasNext()) {
var file = f.next();
var name = file.getName()
var owner = file.getOwner().getEmail()
var lup = file.getLastUpdated()
arr.push([name, '=HYPERLINK("' + file
            .getUrl() + '"; "' + name + '")',owner,lup]);
}
sheet.getRange(1,1, arr.length, arr[0].length).setValues(arr);
}
```

If anyone else has this particular need/issue then feel free to use it.

Chris

Comment: Ive got about 1900 files in my drive at present, I'm not sure what the 'cap' on this script will be. I've read elsewhere about using pages? Still unclear on that. Guess I'll figure it out eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Calls to the sheet.setValues() method will kill your execution time. You're calling it four times for every file you process - which will be a massive overhead. Instead, you should build a two-dimensional array during the file loop, and then make one call to setValues() after the loop.

So create an array:

```
values = [];
```

Then, in the loop, push each row for your spreadsheet into that array as an array itself.

```
values.push([owner, filename, url, lastModified]);
```

Then, after the files loop, make one call to setValues with your array:

```
sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length - 1, 4).setValues(values);
```

Depending on how many files you've got this might be enough to save you the time and get the script to complete. If it doesn't, then it will become complicated...

Comment: Thank you for your time alfiethecoder.                I decided to scrap my original code and start fresh with a clear head. Make better decisions that way, like only using .setValues once.